# what is the name of this parts of speech adjective + preposition

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, parts-of-speech

what is the name of this parts of speech? Adjective + preposition
and how can we use "availabvle of"

Comment: "Available of" doesn't sound right.  Please give an example of a sentence using this pair of words together.  While you're at it, give an example of "Adjective + preposition" that you want to know about.  Otherwise, close.

Comment: Mostly grammars have no special name. They speak of adjective + preposition. An adjective even when it has a complement (with a prep) remains an adjective, it doesn't change its word class.

Comment: Adjective + preposition
1. Are you good at sport?
2.He is  afraid of insects.

 Available of - The researchers were able to establish a manufacturing method that efficiently uses the intrinsic surface area available of this nano-material.